# Expectation of the distance difference.

Tags: probability, expectation

We have a $17$ people siting at the vertices of a big circular table with a constant distance between every two neighbour. After an hour they are rearranged. We choose arbitrary two people. Let $X$ be a (positive) difference between their distances  before and after rearrangement. How to calculate expectation of $X$?

Note that maximum distance is 8.

I was thinking about to express $X$ with $X_i$ which is $1$ if the difference is $i$ and else $0$. So $$X = X_1+...+X_8$$ and thus $$ E(X) = E(X_1)+...+E(X_8)$$ 
But how to calculate $E(X_i)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that distances before and after rearrangement are independent, one can compute it by brute force.

Considering the possible changes of the distance one can compile the following table:
$$
\begin{array}
\Delta X& N_X & \text{Example}\\
7& 2 & 1\leftrightarrow 8\\
6& 4 & 1\leftrightarrow 7, 2\leftrightarrow 8\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
1& 14 & 1\leftrightarrow 2, 2\leftrightarrow 3, \dots, 7\leftrightarrow 8\\
0& 8 & 1\leftrightarrow 1, 2\leftrightarrow 2, \dots, 8\leftrightarrow 8\\
\end{array}
$$

Then the expectation value is:
$$
E(X)=\frac{\sum_X X N_X}{\sum_X N_X}=\frac{21}{8}.
$$

Essentially $N_X$ is the number of cells in the $X$-th super- and subdiagonals of the $8\times8$ matrix with $X$ being the "distance" of these diagonals from the main one.

The above result can be readily generalized on arbitrary odd number $2n+1$ of person:
$$
E(X)=\frac{2\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(n-i)i}{n^2}=\frac{n^2-1}{3n}.
$$

Comment: @ChristianF I have added the answer for arbitrary odd number. $N_X$ is the overall number of pairs composed from "old" and "new" distances with given difference.

Comment: Thanks, what about a pair with $X=0$.

Comment: @ChristianF I cannot deduce this result. In any case it is not generally true for an odd set of people as the example $(12345)\rightarrow(13524)$ shows.

Comment: What about if $n=4k+3$?

Comment: @ChristianF I do not believe that this problem can be somehow connected with the expectation value. I personally find the question "under which condition at least one pair of person will be necessarily equally distant before and after rearrangement"  interesting enough for asking it separately (especially if you have some evidence that this is true.)

Comment: I aware of this now, average is to high. I tried to use probabilistic method to solve the problem, that is to find a pair with $X=0$. Any other idea how to attack this problem with probabilistic method?